# If else from output as a result of input from user- Java Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have used JQuery to multiply a number input by the user the website by 52.  This works however I am struggling to get the "output-value" in the middle of a sentence without it deleting the end of the sentence when the user inputs his number.

Anyone know how to avoid it?  I have tried  which seems to work on some but just wont on mine.

Also, once an user can see the output, I am trying to put a button in so that when the output is within certain numbers it prints out another sentence below.  This does not come up.

Please find what I have so far below;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">

<p>How many times do you have drink coke each week?</p><br>
<p></p>
<input type="text" id="input-value" /> times a week.<br>
<p></p><br>

<p>With 52 weeks in a year, the number of Coke's you would need for the year is at least  
    <output type="text" id="output-value" /> cans </p>

<p>Click the button to find out the best membership plan for you</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var $output = $("#output-value");
$("#input-value").keyup(function() {
var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
$output.val(value*52);
});
function myFunction()
{
var x="";
var $output = $("#output-value");
if ($output<120)
{
x="Good man";
}
else ($output>120)
{
x= "Bad";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>
```

Any Help wouldbemuch appreciated!

Here it is on JSFiddle working the way i have described, you will notice the problems.

Cheers

James

Comment: you have not posted your fiddle link at the bottom,  though you have mentioned it.

Comment: True, apologies for that

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TYXMr/27/ @jai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your were close. When changing `$ouput` value, you can concatenate the string 'cans' after:

```
$output.val(value*52 + ' cans');
```

Then, in your function, if you want the condition to work, you have to parse the value :

```
var $output = parseInt($("#output-value").val(), 10);
```

And your else doesnt need a condition. Your final code is :

```
var $output = $("#output-value");
$("#input-value").keyup(function() {
    var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
    $output.val(value*52 + ' cans');
});
function myFunction()
{
    var x="";
    var $output = parseInt($("#output-value").val(), 10);
    if ($output<120)
    {
        x="Good man";
    }
    else
    {
        x= "Bad";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ep6JE/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap this with doc ready block:

```
$(function(){
   var $output = $("#output-value");
   $("#input-value").keyup(function() {
     var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
     $output.val(value*52);
   });
});

function myFunction()
{
   var x="";
   var $output = $("#output-value");
   /// your code
}
```